# Using Facebook Advance Matching Pixel with Google Tag Manager

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

The basic Pixel init is working just fine with GTM and now I wanna to add Advance Matching with GTM so I have a question about security.
Is it ok to send not hashed aEmail, aPhone, aFirstName as GTM variables? I saw that AirBNB is hashing their values and maybe there are some functions for that.
This Pixel init tag is fired on every page load, and aEmail, aPhone, aFirstName are GTM variables. Thanks

```
<script>
  pixelId = '123456789';
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
  n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
  document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', pixelId, { 
    em: '{{aEmail}}', 
    ph: '{{aPhone}}',
    fn: '{{aFirstName}}'
  });
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
})
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id='+ pixelId +'&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Comment: The documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/05/31/advanced-matching-pixel/) for the Advance Matching pixel says that " Data will be hashed automatically via a dedicated function in FB pixel", that does not sound like you need to hash it yourself (no first hand experience, so this is a comment rather than answer).

Comment: They are hashed, you are right but the problem is with that they are hashed only on pixel init, but in dataLayer the values are visible. I'm asking is there any way with GTM to I use predefined hash function and to say to pixel not to hash it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further at the [documentation for the Advance Matching pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking#advanced_match) it says:

> Use any of the following data types **in clear text or sha256-hashed**
>   format:
>
> email, phone number, first name, last name, city, state, zip gender
>   date of birth.
>
> [...]
>
> If you pass clear text data through the pixel, Facebook hashes all the
>   data using the sha256 algorithm at the browser.
>
> Before you send any data, in **pre-hashed data** or clear text format,
>   check for correct formatting

So you can hash the data yourself with SHA256 in the datalayer. According to the docs this does not require any special settings for the pixel.

Comment: Thanks, it's working with basic sha256 from PHP. Mark as resolved